# c++ reinterpret_cast a integer

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast, offsetof

I came across following c++ code:

```
 #define OFFSETOF_MEMBER(t, f) \
  (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&reinterpret_cast<t*>(16)->f) - static_cast<uintptr_t>(16u)) // NOLINT
```

where t is a type, f is a field name. I wonder why can we put a integer 16 as parameter of reinterpret_cast.

Comment: Note that this is Undefined Behavior. C++ does have `offset_of`, which is a macro defined by every implementation; some implementations will define it similar to this.

Comment: ^ the macro is `offsetof`  , and it's UB to use it on a non-standard-layout class

Answer (score 1):

16 is the address we're assigning to the pointer, which lets us calculate the offset of the specified member. The address of a pointer is just a number, so we can abuse this fact in order to get information about our structures/classes.

Say we have a struct:

```
struct point { 
    //Assuming 32-bit integer sizes. 
    //For 64-bit integersizes, 0x0, 0x8, 0x10 for the integer offsets
    int x; //Offset 0x0
    int y; //Offset 0x4
    int z; //Offset 0x8
}; static_assert(sizeof(point) == 12 /* or 0xC in hex */);
```

We use the macro:

```
OFFSETOF_MEMBER(point, y);
```

Expanding the macro, we get:

```
(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&reinterpret_cast<point*>(16)->y) - static_cast<uintptr_t>(16u)
```

Another way of expressing the `reinterpret_cast<point*>(16)->y` could be had like so: `point * myPt = 16u;` we know 16 is not a valid address, but the compiler doesn't, and so long as we don't try to read the address we're pointing to, we're okay.

Next, we can simplify all of `&reinterpret_cast<point*>(16)->y` to: `&myPt->y`. We know from above that y is @ offset 0x4, and since myPt is 16: `16 + 0x4 = 20`

Then we have `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(20u) - static_cast<uintptr_t(16u)` or `20 - 16`, which gives us the offset of y, that is, 0x4.

Answer (score 0):

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> 3) A value of any integral or enumeration type can be converted to a pointer type. [...]

So, `reinterpret_cast<>` is partly designed to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Integer 16 is just a memory address. Expression `reinterpret_cast<t*>(16)` simply means "interpret the object at address 16 as type `t`", but you know that there's no such `t` object at the address. Theoretically, `16` could be replaced by any 4x (32bit) or 8x (64bit) integer. If you choose `0`, the macro can be simplified as:

```
#define OFFSETOF_MEMBER(t, f) \
  (reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&reinterpret_cast<t*>(0)->f))
```

See [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) for more information.

Comment: But note that this code is deep into undefined behavior. The reason that `offset_of` is defined in the standard library is that the standard library ships with a compiler, and can take advantage of known behavior of that compiler. It's not an example of good, portable code.